# Do we have AjaxOnly Attribute for Web Api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

In my project ,I have a class named AjaxOnlyAttribute that restricts Ajax requests to be shown if the request is not in ajax ...
my code is like below:

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute 
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

and I use it in controllers like this:[AjaxOnly]

It works fine in asp.net mvc ,but it doesnt work in asp.net web api 
Can anyone help please?

Comment: I believe this is due to the fact that you inherit from class ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, which only resides on MVC

Comment: Yes,I want this approach for web api methods